# R - Rolling correlation of each column with each other column

Tags: r, xts

Hello and apologies for asking this, as I think variations on the question have been answered many times, but I cannot seem to apply those to my specific problem.

I have a huge time series of stock returns of many different companies that looks something like this

```
library(tidyquant)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

df = data.frame(tq_get("AAPL"))

ts = df[ , 3:8] %>%
     xts(order.by = as.Date(df[ , 2], "%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
     Return.calculate()
```

Now I need to do rolling correlations of each column with each other column in my time series.
For just two columns the following works perfectly

```
rollcor = rollapply(ts, 63, function(x) cor(x[ , 1],x[ , 2]), by.column=FALSE)
```

But I cannot get it to work with `apply()` over columns, so I tried a for loop to correlate at least the first column with all the others

```
rollcors = data.frame(ts)
for(j in ncol(rollcors)) {
  rollcors[ , j] = rollapply(rollcors, 63, function(x) cor(x[ , 1],x[ , j]), by.column=FALSE, fill = NA)
}
```

But this doesn't replace each column with a new one containing correlations like I hoped it would.

I'd also prefer to keep the output vertically oriented like it is now, for better readability. My perfect result would be a list of dataframes/time series, each containing the correlations of one column with all other columns, which I could then furter manipulate (daily medians, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This provides the correlation matrix unravelled into a row for each date.  There will be n*n columns where ts has n columns:

```
r1 <- rollapplyr(ts, 63, cor, fill = NA, by.column = FALSE)
```

or this will show only the lower triangle and will have choose(n, 2) columns:

```
ccor <- function(x) { cc <- cor(x); cc[lower.tri(cc)] }
r2 <- rollapplyr(X, 63, ccor, fill = NA, by.column = FALSE)
```

This can be used to assign column names, if needed.

```
paste_ <- function(...) paste(..., sep = "_")
names_mat <- do.call("outer", list(names(ts), names(ts), paste_))
names(r1) <- names_mat
names(r2) <- names_mat[lower.tri(names_mat)]
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.
And it was such a small thing I would have never thought of it.

Comment: @Grothendieck Thank you, the solution is great. However, the column names change to V1, V2, etc, so it is hard to learn which columns have which correlation. Do you have an idea how to keep meaningful names?

Comment: Have added that at end.